# How to fit the solution of a NSolve with a NDSolve embedded

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, fitting, nonlinear

I have a system : $$s'(t)=A n+B a(t)\\a'(t)=C s(t) $$

Then I define the function $\tau(n)$ as the solution of the equation :
$$a(\tau(n))n=1$$
and I'm looking for the parameters $A,B,C$ with a fit.

Here is my code :

```
at[t_?NumericQ, a0_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, 
  N0_?NumericQ] := 
 s[t] /. NDSolve[{s'[t] == a0*N0 + a1*a[t], a'[t] == a2*s[t], 
     s[0] == 0, a[0] == 0}, a, {t, 0, 100}][[1]]

Tsol[a0_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, N0_?NumericQ] := 
 t /. NSolve[at[t, a0, a1, a2, N0]*N0 == 1, t][[1]]

n0 = 10000;
data0 = {{n0/32, 40}, {n0/16, 36}, {n0/8, 30}, {n0/4, 28}, {n0/2, 
    22}, {n0, 18}};
data = N[Table[{Log[data0[[n, 1]]], data0[[n, 2]]}, {n, 1, 
     Length[data0]}]];

fit1[x_] = 
 NonlinearModelFit[
  data, {Tsol[AA, BB, CC, Exp[x]], AA >= 0, BB >= 0, CC >= 0}, {AA, 
   BB, CC}, x]
```

I'm using the logarithm because I think it is more adapted.

But it seems that I made mistakes in the code. Could you help please ?

Comment: Are you looking to generalise this to more complicated systems of ODEs? You system can be solved analytically.

Comment: thanks I had not noticed this ! But indeed I'd like to generalize this method to more complicated systems of ODEs.

Comment: The equations use in the `NDSolve` are different from those in the text. You used `a'[t] == a2*s[t]` rather than `a'[t] == a2*a[t]`. Please edit your question to reflect the correct one.

Comment: Your definition for `at` will not work like this. `t` is numeric and you're trying to use it as an independent variable. What exactly should `at` return?

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess at what you want to do exactly, but is this what you need?

```
at[t0_?NumericQ, a0_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, N0_?NumericQ] := Block[{t},
  NDSolveValue[
    {s'[t] == a0*N0 + a1*a[t], a'[t] == a2*s[t], s[0] == 0, a[0] == 0}, 
    a[t0], {t, 0, t0}
  ]
];

Tsol[a0_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, N0_?NumericQ] := Block[{t},
  t /. FindRoot[at[t, a0, a1, a2, N0]*N0 == 1, {t, 1}]
];
```

Test that the functions work:

```
In[44]:= at[1, 1, 1, 1, 10]

Out[44]= 5.43081

In[57]:= Tsol[1, 1, 1, 10]

Out[57]= 0.141304
```